# Resume video where it is left off in android

Tags: android, onresume

I want to resume a video where it is closed the last time. I have tried it but the problem is that when I close the video the `last_position` is saved correctly. But when I open that video again, the `last_position` is 0 meaning that the video opens from the start. How can I take the value of the `last_position` present in onPause() method and use in onResume() ?

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(activity, PlayerActivity.class);
              intent.putExtra("position", position);
              activity.startActivity(intent);
         }
   }  

public class  PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
SimpleExoPlayer player;
long last_position;
PlayerView playerView;
int position = 0;
ArrayList<Files> myFiles = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 0);
    String path = myFiles.get(position).getPath();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
    player= new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
    DataSource.Factory factory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory
            (this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "My App"));
    ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();

    MediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(factory, extractorsFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
    playerView.setPlayer(player);
    playerView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    player.prepare(mediaSource);

    if (last_Position > 0){
        simpleExoPlayer.seekTo(last_Position);
    }

    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
    player.getPlaybackState();
    if (player != null){
        State.last_Position = (int) player.getCurrentPosition();
        State.click_Position = position;
    }
}


@Override
    protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      if (position != State.click_Position){                
            State.last_Position = 0;
      }
      player.seekTo(State.last_Position);
      player.getPlaybackState();
      player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
 }


abstract static class State {
    public static int last_Position = 0;
    public static int click_Position = -1;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:**
Create a static variable

```
public  static int  lastPositionTime = 0;
```

**Step 2:** Save the current position in this variable in onPause State. Check one condition

```
if(lastPositionTime == 0){
   //save your current position
}
```

**Step 3:** in OnResume call the seekTo method and pass lastPositionTime

NOTE: your last position variable is not in static so it's rolled back to default value use a static variable for localPostion

Comment: Could you check above and edit what is difference, I am unable to see how to pass value in onResume as of step 3.

Comment: what you're getting in State.lastPosition in onResume can you print or debug then let me know.

Comment: I checked that and when I open and close only one video it works fine. but when I open a second video and go back to first one, State.lastPosition becomes zero and so it opens from start.

Comment: Hey if you have multiple videos go with hashmap or shared preference and do you have a video id for differentiating the 1st, 2nd video

Comment: yes I do have video id could you explain it with some code?

Comment: Use static keyword hash map and store the key(Video I'd ) value (lastPosition) and while opening the 2nd video pass video id and get your lastPosition, If you need more clearification I will send code through mail fisal17.tf@gmail.com

Comment: I sent you email

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code it will help you.

```
 //create a class for manage state or sharedPref
   abstract class State {
   public  static int  lastPosition = 0;
   public  static int  clickPosition = -1;
}

 //update below line in your onPause()
 if (player != null){
    State.lastPosition= player.getCurrentPosition();
    State.clickPosition = position;
}

  //remove code from below method
  @Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  player.seekTo(State.last_Position);
  player.getPlaybackState();
  player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
  }

 // on the click of video you can check if position is same as State.clickPosition then it is not new video
  holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          if(postion != State.clickPosition){
         //this is new video you can reset position
          State.lastPosition = 0;
          }
          Intent intent = new Intent(activity, PlayerActivity.class);
          intent.putExtra("position", position);
          activity.startActivity(intent);
     }
   }  


 playerView.setPlayer(player);
    playerView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    player.prepare(mediaSource);
    //here you can pass your last position
    if(State.lastPosition>0) player.seekTo(State.lastPosition);
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Comment: It is behaving in the same way as before. The position is 0 at this point as well.

Comment: where is the button in code of pause and resume

Comment: Its the default methods in simple exo player.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but there is still one problem that every video starts at the time where the last one was closed. Each video should resume at its own time where it was closed. Now if you close first video at a time, the second video will start from a point where first was closed.

Comment: in the every new video click you can reset last position with 0 again, it will solve your problem

Comment: I have tried but could not determine which is the new video to reset the position. If you could show some code that would be of great help.

Comment: I have edited the code above as when I open a video, close it and open a second one and go back to first, it opens from the start instead of the last position.

Comment: I have added that above.

Comment: It is working in same way as before. If you move back to previously played video it opens from the start